# Vertex color interpolation artifacts

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, vertex-shader, vertex

I display a "curved tube" and color its vertices based on their distance to the plane the curve lays on.

It works mostly fine, however, when I reduce the resolution of the tube, artifacts starts to appear in the tube colors.

Those artifacts seem to depend on the camera position. If I move the camera around, sometimes the artifacts disappear. Not sure it makes sense.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gz1wu369/15/
[image]

I do not know if there is actually a problem in the interpolation or if it is just a "screen" artifact.

Afterwards I render the scene to a texture, looking at it from the "top". It then looks like a "deformation" field that I use in another shader, hence the need for continuous color.

I do not know if it is the expected behavior or if there is a problem in my code while setting the vertices color.

Would using the THREEJS Extrusion tools instead of the tube geometry solve my issue?

```
const tubeGeo = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(closedSpline, steps, radius, curveSegments, false);

const count = tubeGeo.attributes.position.count;
tubeGeo.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(count * 3), 3));

const colors = tubeGeo.attributes.color;
const color = new THREE.Color();


 for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  const pp = new THREE.Vector3(
    tubeGeo.attributes.position.array[3 * i],
    tubeGeo.attributes.position.array[3 * i + 1],
    tubeGeo.attributes.position.array[3 * i + 2]);
  const distance = plane.distanceToPoint(pp);
  const normalizedDist = Math.abs(distance) / radius;
  const t2 = Math.floor(i / (curveSegments + 1));
  color.setHSL(0.5 * t2 / steps, .8, .5);
  const green = 1 - Math.cos(Math.asin(Math.abs(normslizedDist)));
  colors.setXYZ(i, color.r, green, 0);
}
```

Low-res tubes with "Normals" material shows different artifact
[image]

High resolution tube hide the artifacts:
[image]

Comment: You can try calculating the color per fragment in the fragment shader, instead of per vertex on the cpu. (Also, set material.side = THREE.DoubleSide.)

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for the suggestion. Yes ideally coloring would happen in the fragment shader but I can not think of a good way to approach the problem. Would you have a suggestion by any chance?

Comment: For a quick fix, I suggest you use a high-poly model. If that is not possible, and you need tutorial help on how to write a custom `ShaderMaterial`, I suggest you post your question on the three.js forum at https://discourse.threejs.org.